# Problem in math question

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have a sum as follows.

> Two small balls of equal mass can move inside a rough endless
>   horizontal tube of length $l$. One ball impinges with velocity $u$ on the
>   other at rest. If the friction of the tube produces a retardation $f$ in
>   either ball, and if after impact the balls just meet up again, prove
>   that $2lf=(u^{2})e$ where $e$ is the co-efficient of restitution.

My problem is how can there be another collision immediately afterwards? In the sum it says if

> after impact the balls just meet up again

how can the balls meet again? Have I misunderstood the sum? Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is better off in the physics stack exchange.

Comment: Also, the title is rather vague: most questions posted at math.se are a "problem in math question."! And ironically, this is more a "problem in physics question."

Comment: No actually @rlgordonma and @ amWhhy this a Math question.. I want to know if it is possible to have an immediate collision since normally when a collision like the first happens, the velocity of the mass which moves to the same direction which had a zero velocity early would have a higher velocity than the other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @harsh: even if that were true, have you thought about the units involved?  Is $f$ the mass of the balls?  If so, then the LHS has units of (mass)(length), while the RHS has units of (length^2)/(time^2) time whatever the units are of this coefficient (which, in my encounters with such parameters, are typically dimensionless).

Comment: Is this the original question, or have you translated it?

Comment: @rlgordonma no the *f* is retardation..so the units are fine in both sides.. @ Chris Eagle I have not modified, this is the original question.

Comment: Should this say "two small balls _of_ equal mass"?

Comment: I'm not clear on the shape of the tube.  Is it cylindrical with _width_ $l$?

Comment: yes @TrevorWilson someone had edited it the other way.sorry. I understood it is of length *l*.

Comment: To make this a math question I think you would need to define restitution and retardation for us.  I tend to agree with other commentators that this would get a better response at Physics.SE

Comment: "after impact the balls just meet up again" does not mean that the balls meet again "just after the impact". It means that the second time they meet, they *just meet*, i.e., collision happens at the moment when their relative velocity drops to zero.

Comment: @harsh This is a nice question. Mechanics is very much within the sphere of mathematics, so don't let people get you down. (In fact, all three of the Cambridge STEP papers have a mechanics section on them.) Could you supply a link to the question, because some things are unclear. Is your $f$ the coefficient of static friction ($f=\mu$?) or the static frictional force ($f \le \mu R$?).

Comment: @FlybyNight Thanks. :) This is all given for the problem. No other data was given. I took this from a book, not from a site.